# Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> Value items can't be accessed. C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary

I'm playing around with Dictionaries and the new fancy 4.0 dynamic types inside a dictionary.

I have a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> dynamicDic
```

And I populate it like this:

```
dynamicDic.Add("First", new Class1());
dynamicDic.Add("Second", new Class2());
```

For the sake of testing/practising Class1 and Class2 are quite simple:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Element { get; set; }

    public List<Class2> Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Property { get; set; }

    public string Field;
}
```

I create two other classes that map class1 and class2 and they are virtually the same so ClassMap1 and ClassMap2. I'll just include CalssMap1 though:

```
public class ClassMap1: BaseClassMap1
{
    public ClassMap1()
    {
        var r = new Class1();
        Children = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
            {
                {"Element", r.GetType().GetProperty("Element")},
                {"Class1", r.GetType().GetProperty("Class1")}
            };
        Name = "Root";
        ObjectType = typeof (Class1);
        Parent = "RootElement";
        HasParent = false;
        HasChildren = true;
        IsClass = r.GetType().IsClass;
    }
}
```

And I create a base class: BaseClass1()

```
public class BaseClass1
{
    private String _Name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    private Type _ObjectType;

    public Type ObjectType
    {
        get { return _ObjectType; }
        set { _ObjectType = value; }
    }

    private String _Parent;

    public String Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; }
        set { _Parent = value; }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> _Children;

    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Children
    {
        get { return _Children; }
        set { _Children = value; }
    }

    private bool _HasParent;

    public bool HasParent
    {
        get { return _HasParent; }
        set { _HasParent = value; }
    }

    private bool _HasChildren;

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return _HasChildren; }
        set { _HasChildren = value; }
    }

    private bool _IsClass;

    public bool IsClass
    {
        get { return _IsClass; }
        set { _IsClass = value; }
    }
}
```

I populate the classes with data, not really important what data :)

Yet when I try to access the values through a Linq statement:

```
var a = _classObjects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == node.Name).Value;
```

a only gives me:-

```
a.Equals(), a.GetType(), a.GetEnumerator() or a.ToString()
```

I would like to be able to have it do this instead (with intellisense)...

```
a.Children
a.Name
a.HasParent
```

etc...

Anyone got any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Oops got that completely wrong... Sorry :|
Edited above...

Comment: You're calling your `Class1` parameterless constructor as the first line of the `Class1` parameterless constructor. That's not going to work out well. In terms of Intellisense - the values will only be populated at execution time. It's not clear how you expect Intellisense to know what to do at build time.

Comment: You're using a `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>`, so the type of `a` will be `dynamic`. You can't get intellisense on a `dynamic` variable, because the compiler doesn't know what the run-time type will be.

Comment: DOH! That was some Homer Simpson moment

Comment: You call "var r = new Class1();" inside Class1() constructor... looks like stackoverflow. I think Intellisense will not work with dynamic.

Comment: Richard called it above, then the other Richard called it below. Thanks Guys. Now how do I give you some Rep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic` classes are all about run-time (**NOT** compile-time) discovery.  How do you expect Intellisense to know what to do?

Using `dynamic` classes incurs a high performance overhead.  I really suggest that you make it: `Dictionary<string, dynamic> dynamicDic`.

Or define a `MyBaseClass` and make it: `Dictionary<string, MyBaseClass> myDic`.

Comment: Yeah good point with the string instead of dynamic Key. I was just playing around with different ways of adding stuff into Dictionaries and dynamic came first before I thought that it would just be a string :)

Comment: Use the tool for what it is designed for.  Don't use it just because its handy.  `dynamics` are very powerful and are great in certain situations, but should **NOT** be used day-in day-out.

Comment: We gotta learn somewhere. Learning stuff is a day in day out situation.

Comment: You are correct.  And I apologise for the above comment.  Learning is always to be encouraged.